# Rails 3.2 Email Address "If Blank"

Tags: facebook, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, omniauth

So I had a problem where Omni-Auth Facebook wasn't returning an email address for SOME (20-30%) user accounts, therefore the accounts wouldn't be registered because of an "email can't be blank error."

So I decided to solve this by automatically generating an email address based on the user's facebook ID if omniauth couldn't get the email address...

Now... of course... the problem with my solution (as you'll see below) is that it started saving the auto-generated email address REGARDLESS of whether or not omniauth was returning an email address. (For example my email always worked fine, but it was replaced with 123213@facebook.com)

Basically what I want is this: if a user has already supplied an email address then it just stays with the original. If they haven't, and the email address can't be gotten from omniauth, then it generates a new one.

```
 def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.email = "#{auth.provider}-#{auth.uid}@liquid-radio.com"
    user.password = user.password_confirmation = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(n=6)
    if auth.provider == "facebook"
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.email = auth.info.email = "#{auth.uid}@facebook.com"
    else      
      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
    end
    user.save
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to move this line:

```
user.email = "#{auth.provider}-#{auth.uid}@liquid-radio.com"
```

down into the "else" case, since it only (presumably) applies to non-Facebook users.

Aside from that, try changing this:

```
user.email = auth.info.email = "#{auth.uid}@facebook.com"
```

to this:

```
user.email ||= auth.info.email || "#{auth.uid}@facebook.com"
```

A breakdown of what this does:

- if the user already has an email, it doesn't change it
- if there's a value in `auth.info.email` and the user doesn't have an email yet, set it
- if there isn't a value in `auth.info.email`, punt and use the generated version

You could write this out long-form in Ruby as:

```
if user.email
  # do nothing
elsif auth.info.email
  user.email = auth.info.email
else
  user.email = "#{auth.uid}@facebook.com"
end
```

Note: the solution above will not work if the liquid-radio.com line is still above the `if auth.provider` part - the user will ALWAYS have a value in the email field in that case.

Another note: this code will not update a user's email from their Facebook auth if it changes. This may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Thanks! I actually did removed that line before I saw your reply because I couldn't figure out why I'd put in there in the first place. :) It seems to be working just by removing that, but I'll clean up my code a bit.

Comment: Is the first one supposed to be user.email ||= auth.info.email or user.email || auth.info.email?

Comment: Curiously enough this doesn't really work. It logs the user in... but leaves the password blank. My guess is that in the authentication.rb I need to have attr_accessible :create, :destroy, :index, :provider, :uid, :user_id, :email. Will test this.